# Django user model (Employee and Customer)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am currently working on a mobile app delivery system which involves two types of users: "Employee" and "Customer". Each type of user would have different views and permissions within the app. In addition, each type of user would their own "profile", if you will. The employee's profile purpose is mostly just to designate company roles. The customer's profile is mostly used to save an address for delivery.

I am trying to get some opinions on what the best practice to achieve something like this would be. I can't decide if its better to use AbstractBaseUser or AbstractUser.

Below is a visual of the models I want to create along with their relationship:

[image: visual for User models]

Below is the the user/models.py file that I mocked up:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    USER_TYPES = (
        ('Employee', 'employee'),
        ('Customer', 'customer')
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=USER_TYPES)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'


# if user.user_type == 'Employee'
class EmployeeProfile(models.Model):
    EMPLOYEE_ROLES = (
        ('Driver', 'driver'),
        ('Production', 'production'),
        ('Manager', 'manger')
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=EMPLOYEE_ROLES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user


# if user.user_type == 'Customer'
class CustomerProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, help_text="State Abbreviation (ex: OH)")
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

I know that I would also need to use Django signals or something similar to create a User profile (for either an employee or customer, on user creation).

Comment: is this worked? I am working on a similar. after creating different user-type accounts I have to send messages between them. ( customer can send message to employee and vice versa ). I also want to save different profile info with each user-type.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works
But according to the design pattern standards, it can be said to put a Boolianfield in the user named is_employee and all the information of both types of users should be in AbstractUser, but with null=True and blank=True values.
This way you have a single user with which it can be separated by a is_employee field
I hope it was useful

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).